# Unexpected panic when downcasting Any

Tags: rust, casting

Take the following example:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait AsAny {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}
impl<T: Any> AsAny for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Box<u8> = Box::new(0u8);
    let _b = a.as_any().downcast_ref::<Box<u8>>().expect("1");

    let a: Box<u8> = Box::new(0u8);
    let a: Box<dyn Any> = a;
    let _b = a.as_any().downcast_ref::<Box<u8>>().expect("2");
}
```

The above panics on the `expect("2")`. I still can't quite pin my finger on why the type is getting erased. Yes, `a` gets upcasted to a `Box<dyn Any>`, but how come it no longer holds the type information so that it can get downcasted later?

Are there any (safe) workarounds for this? I already have a working workaround with `Box::into_raw`, `Box::from_raw`, and a pointer cast, but I'd prefer to avoid unsafe.

Edit: To avoid the XY problem, my real question is that I have a `Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait>` that I need to cast into a `SomeConcreteType`. I know about the `downcast*` methods on `Box`, but unfortunately they aren't much help in my situation.

Comment: `a.downcast_ref::<u8>()` works

Comment: Your `as_any()` method casts _the `Box<dyn Any>` itself_ to `dyn Any`, not just its contents.

Comment: @isaactfa I was aware of that, which is why I did the `downcast_ref::<Box<u8>>` (Box -> Any -> Box again). I also tried variations on that too and they didn't work. That is why I am a bit puzzled

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks for that, didn't realize that worked. Unfortunately, in my actual scenario, the `let trait_object_box: Box<dyn SomeTrait> = ...; let any_box: Box<dyn Any> = trait_object_box;` complains about mismatched types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
let a: Box<u8> = Box::new(0u8);
let a: Box<dyn Any> = a;
let _b = a.as_any().downcast_ref::<Box<u8>>().expect("2");
```

In order to understand why this compiles, but does not execute as you expect, you need to understand [the method resolution algorithm](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html), and the fact that `AsAny` is a trait you have blanket implemented for **any `Sized` type.**

`a.as_any()` has to be resolved to some specific function call. The search proceeds as follows:

- Is there any method named `as_any` which has a receiver type of `Box<dyn Any>`? No.
- …a receiver type of `&Box<dyn Any>`? Yes!

See, `Box<dyn Any>` is a `Sized` type, so it implements `AsAny`, and the first thing the compiler tries is *referencing* it, not *dereferencing* it. Thus, the fact that the `Box` *contains* `dyn Any` never gets involved.

If we're careful we can demonstrate this:

```rust
let a: Box<u8> = Box::new(0u8);
let a: Box<dyn Any> = a;
assert_eq!(TypeId::of::<Box<dyn Any>>(), <dyn Any>::type_id(a.as_any()));
```

> ...my real question is that I have a `Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait>`...

If you want to be able to downcast from a trait object, *that trait* must provide downcasting support. Otherwise the run-time information just does not exist; the *only* information a trait object has at run time is the data pointer and the vtable pointer, and the vtable does not contain a `TypeId`. The simplest version of the trick is to incorporate `as_any` into the trait:

```rust
use std::any::{TypeId, Any};

trait SomeOtherTrait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
    
    // and also your other important methods
}
impl SomeOtherTrait for u8 {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Box<u8> = Box::new(0u8);
    let a: Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait> = a;
    assert_eq!(TypeId::of::<u8>(), <dyn Any>::type_id(a.as_any()));
    let _b = a.as_any().downcast_ref::<u8>().expect("2");
}
```

These assertions pass.

Note that if you do things this way, is critical that `SomeOtherTrait` has an actual `as_any()` method that *each implementor* implements; that is what makes `SomeOtherTrait` vtables contain the information that is necessary.

In future versions of Rust, this may be made simpler by [trait upcasting](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65991), which might allow you to simply declare `trait SomeOtherTrait: Any` and then coerce `Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait>` to `Box<dyn Any>` and `&dyn SomeOtherTrait` to `&dyn SomeOtherTrait`.

For now, the easiest way to get this done is to use a library that uses even more elaborate tricks to provide convenient downcasting attached to your trait, like [`downcast-rs`](https://docs.rs/downcast-rs/). (Unfortunately, I don't quite understand how it works so I don't have an explanation to include here.) This allows you to not require all your trait implementors to include `fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any { self }`.

(If `SomeOtherTrait` is not a trait you control, then there is nothing you can do.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I do not control the trait in question (`DynClone`) but was able to solve this (at least using nightly) using your trait upcasting recommendation. Edited my question to show what I came up with.

Comment: @GregoryConrad You should post that as an answer, not an edit to the question. (It's okay to answer your own question, and it's okay to post an answer even if you're accepting someone else's.)

Comment: Alright, will do 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin Reid's answer, I was able to use trait upcasting (at least on nightly) to do this (in my original question, I was attempting to cast the `DynClone` to a concrete type):

```rust
trait ClonableAny: Any + DynClone {}          // define custom trait that you own with Any
dyn_clone::clone_trait_object!(ClonableAny);  // something needed for just my particular use case with DynClone
impl<T: Clone + 'static> ClonableAny for T {} // blanket impl for all applicable types

let data: Box<dyn Any> = data.clone(); // trait upcast (the clone() is for my use case)
let casted_type = *data
    .downcast::<C::T>()
    .expect("Types should be properly enforced due to generics");
```

The key is to make a trait that you own that inherits from Any. Then you can use a blanket implementation that implements it for all types that have and the other trait.